# ZF2 & Doctrine2 Annotation for One To Many Relationship

Tags: php, forms, zend-framework, annotations

I've problem using ZF2 form annotation and doctrine2 annotation.

I have 2 entities : Movement and Element, and a One To Many Relation between this two entities (One movement has many Elements).

So in the Movement Entity Class I have this annotation :

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Application\Entity\CcMovementElement", mappedBy="movement", cascade={"persist"})
 * 
 * @ComposedObject({ "target_object":"Application\Entity\CcMovementElement", "is_collection":"false", "options":{"count":1, "should_create_template":true, "allow_add" : true}})
 * @Form\Attributes({"class":"movement-element"})
 */
private $elements;
```

Then in the element entity Class i have this annotation :

```
/**
 * @var \Application\Entity\CcMovement
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Application\Entity\CcMovement", inversedBy="elements")
 * @ORM\JoinColumns({
 *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="movement", referencedColumnName="id", onDelete="CASCADE")
 * })
 * @Form\Attributes({"type":"hidden"})
 * @Form\Filter({"name": "Int"})
 */
```

then i build the form in the controller like this :

```
$entity = new CcMovement();
$builder = new AnnotationBuilder($this->getEntityManager());
    $form = $builder->createForm($entity);
    $form->setHydrator(new DoctrineHydrator($this->getEntityManager(), get_class($entity)));
    $form->bind($entity);
```

The form is generated like i wan't.

When i submit form, i use this code in controller

```
     $entity = new CcMovement();
    $builder = new AnnotationBuilder($this->getEntityManager());
        $form = $builder->createForm($entity);
        $form->setHydrator(new DoctrineHydrator($this->getEntityManager(), get_class($entity)));
        $form->bind($entity);
$form->setData($posts);
        if ($form->isValid()) {
           .... Action if valid
        } else {
           ... Action if error
        }
```

When i create new element, form[elements][0][movement] is not set, that is normal. And with this code it works, when valid i persit the entity.

Now, i wan't to make some change on Element fieldset so i create a class ElementFieldset that extend Zend\Form\Fieldset and i modify Element Entity Class Annotation like this :

```
/**
 * CcMovementElement
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="cc_movement_element", indexes={@ORM\Index(name="fk_element_movement", columns={"movement"})})
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Application\Repository\CcMovementElementRepository")
 * @Form\Type("Application\Form\ElementFieldset") 
 * @Form\Name("movement_element")
 */
class CcMovementElement
{
```

But when i do it $form->isValid Failed, because NotEmpty validator is applyed to form[elements][i][movement].
I only add Annotation Form/Type in Element Entity and ElementFieldSet just extend Zend\Form\Fieldset without any method.

I don't understand what appen...

thanks for help